# How to get source code of curl post request redirect_ur variable?

Tags: php, curl, http-post

i am filling a form using curl post method and the form returns redirect_url value! I am able to print that redirect value but now i want to get source code of redirect_url url . My current get_data code doesnt bring back any data and the text area($result2) is empty. Could you guys help me fix this problem .Thanks

```
<?php

//create array of data to be posted
$post_data['firstName'] = 'Name';
$post_data['action'] = 'Register';

//traverse array and prepare data for posting (key1=value1)
foreach ( $post_data as $key => $value) {
    $post_items[] = $key . '=' . $value;
}

//create the final string to be posted using implode()
$post_string = implode ('&', $post_items);

//create cURL connection
$curl_connection =
  curl_init('http://www.somesite.com/target_url.php');

//set options
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,
  "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1)");
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);


//set data to be posted
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_string);

//perform our request
$result = curl_exec($curl_connection);

//show information regarding the request
print_r(curl_getinfo($curl_connection));
echo curl_errno($curl_connection) . '-' .
                curl_error($curl_connection);

$info = curl_getinfo($curl_connection); 
$url22 = $info['redirect_url'];
echo "redirectValue:".$url22;

//close the connection
curl_close($curl_connection);

$result2 = get_data($url22);

/* gets the data from a URL */

function get_data($url) {

  $ch = curl_init();

  $timeout = 5;

  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,"Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1)");

  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);

  $data = curl_exec($ch);

//perform our request
//$result = curl_exec($curl_connection);


//show information regarding the request
print_r(curl_getinfo($ch));
echo curl_errno($ch) . '-' .
                curl_error($ch);

  curl_close($ch);

  return $data;

}

?>

<br>
<textarea name="tweet" cols="50"rows="5" id="tweet"><?php echo $result2 ?></textarea>
```

Comment: `now i want to get source code of redirect_url url` can you elaborate ? before you were posting values so may be you were getting the `redirect_url` where the request was redirected. What are you doing now ? and again please elaborate.

Comment: $result2=get_data($url22); doesn't return data! How to fix it?

Comment: This could be because of multiple reasons -> the url requires https , needs certain header values to be set etc

Comment: how to find out what header needs to be send ?how to send store and save cookies in curl call ?